# React + Spring Boot deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm having problems deploying a react nodejs application with a spring boot. The spring application works fine with basic HTML/JS and I've got the react app running fine in dev mode, but I seem to be missing something as far as bundling the react and spring properly.

Currently, I can run/deploy my spring boot application with some simple HTML and javascript ajax calls (no react). It runs on my AWS ec2 with no problems.

I can also run my react application in dev mode through node JS "npm start" and point it at my local spring boot application. (I added `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` to `manifest.json`). I'm struggling with the next steps of actually bundling my react application into the war with the rest of my spring application and getting it working. I can't even get a react hello-world page to load without rest calls.

I've tried running `npm run build` and then copying all of the files generated in the `/build` directory to my spring project's `/src/main/resources`.
Specifically I copied:

```
react-app/build/static/* -> spring-app/src/main/resources/static/.

react-app/build/* -> spring-app/src/main/resources/.
```

After building the war (`mvn install`) and running the war locally, I'm getting 404 errors when trying to load the server without any page specified. When I specify index.html, I'm getting errors that it's failing to load the JS and CSS files in my static directory. The same problems happen when I deploy the war to ec2 and try to load pages.

Are there more configuration steps that I'm missing? I'm aware there's probably some base URL config I'll need to do to consume the rest API outside of dev mode, but I can't even get a page to load without any rest calls. I tried moving index.html to various locations like `/resources/static` and `/resources/public`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's a really bad idea to bundle your frontend app in with your backend for many reasons. Big repo, poor separation of concerns, complicated release cycles/deployment, tight coupling, you may have multiple UIs - e.g. web and native, more setup for UI devs who shouldn't need to concern themselves with java or maven etc. Why not have two projects, since they have no dependency on each other, the UI just consumes the API like any other client.

Comment: Yea I agree now haha. I think I'm going to scrap the idea and host the client on heroku or firebase or something, and keep the spring app hosted separately on aws. I can keep the react files much more organized this way.

Comment: Yep I think so!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look into this tutorial from Spring, there is a "frontend-maven-plugin" that you might find very useful. I would ditch the war and just build your spring boot app as a jar, then place your js files in src/main/js, and your index.html in /src/main/resources/static.

The tutorial is available here:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

And the code is available here:

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest/tree/master/basic

Use a webpack.config.js config similar to the one used in the tutorial, and it will "just work" once you build using the maven front end plugin.

As others have suggested, you will be better off separating your front-end and back-end code (keep them in separate repositories).

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'll check this out. I was hoping there was some small configuration change I needed to make but I guess I'll start refactoring my project.

Comment: I can get a very basic app running, but I seem to be having issues building basic CSS files.

Comment: When I run "mvn clean install":

ERROR in ./src/main/js/App.css
[INFO] Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/btillinghast/git/misdeal/src/main/js/App.css: Unexpected token (1:0)
[INFO]
[INFO] > 1 | .App {
[INFO]     | ^
[INFO]   2 |   text-align: center;
[INFO]   3 | }
[INFO]   4 |

Comment: I think you should put your css files in this directory: src/main/resources/static

Comment: Same issue. I'm still getting a syntax error on the first character '.' of my css file. I'm also getting this warning when I run mvn install: [WARNING] npm WARN webpack-cli@2.0.14 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none was installed.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: I've got the same exact webpack dependencies set as the tutorial's.

Comment: I posted the maven output here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837030/maven-install-warnings

Answer (score 3):

I followed the same approach for Production purposes using **frontend-maven-plugin** and **maven-antrun-plugin**.

I used **frontend-maven-plugin** to generate the React bundle (`npm install` and than `npm run build`) and **maven-antrun-plugin** to copy the artifacts to spring boot's public folder.

A great sample project and tutorial can be found [here](https://github.com/kantega/react-and-spring)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem,
Created a folder **webapp/resources** in src folder of the project and copied build folder content generated from npm install and run build.
This solved the issue.

In my project i had the Ui files in **src/main/app** folder and ran npm install and run build commands on it.
And then copied build folder content to src/main/webapp/resources 
https://github.com/Aditya260194/spring-boot-react-app

below is my pom part for build and war

```
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <workingDirectory>${uiResourcesDir}</workingDirectory>
                            <executable>npm.cmd</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>install</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <workingDirectory>${uiResourcesDir}</workingDirectory>
                            <executable>npm.cmd</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>run</argument>
                                <argument>build</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```