# Maven Install Warnings

Tags: reactjs, maven, webpack

I'm new to react and webpack. Maven seems to be unable to process my css files. Running mvn install has a syntax error unexpected token on the first character of my CSS file. Does it have to do with this warning I'm getting?

```
[WARNING] npm WARN webpack-cli@2.0.14 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
```

I tried updating webpack to that version 4.0.0 but that gave me babel-loader issues. I'm new to tracking down maven dependencies. Can anyone take at my package.json config and maven output? Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "misdeal",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "rest": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch -d"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14"
  }
}
```

Here's the maven install output:

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.2:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ misdeal ---
[INFO] Installing node version v4.4.5
[INFO] Copying node binary from C:\Users\btillinghast\.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett\node\4.4.5\node-4.4.5-win-x64.exe to C:\Users\btillinghast\git\misdeal\target\node\node.exe
[INFO] Installed node locally.
[INFO] Installing npm version 3.9.2
[INFO] Unpacking C:\Users\btillinghast\.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett\npm\3.9.2\npm-3.9.2.tar.gz into C:\Users\btillinghast\git\misdeal\target\node\node_modules
[INFO] Installed npm locally.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.2:npm (npm install) @ misdeal ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install' in C:\Users\btillinghast\git\misdeal
[WARNING] npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
[WARNING] npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.3
[WARNING] npm WARN webpack-cli@2.0.14 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.2:webpack (webpack build) @ misdeal ---
[INFO] Running 'webpack.js ' in C:\Users\btillinghast\git\misdeal
[INFO] Hash: 6c98a449ae4f6374613a
[INFO] Version: webpack 1.15.0
[INFO] Time: 1332ms
[INFO]                                           Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
[INFO]     ./src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js  756 kB       0  [emitted]  main
[INFO] ./src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js.map  880 kB       0  [emitted]  main
[INFO]     + 187 hidden modules
[INFO]
[INFO] ERROR in ./src/main/resources/static/App.css
[INFO] Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/btillinghast/git/misdeal/src/main/resources/static/App.css: Unexpected token (1:0)
[INFO]
[INFO] > 1 | .App {
[INFO]     | ^
[INFO]   2 |   text-align: center;
[INFO]   3 | }
[INFO]   4 |
[INFO]
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/js/containers/App.js 13:0-41
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `Webpack`, the version you have is outdated, the current version is `4.5.0` the version you have installed is `1.12.2` and `Webpack CLI` requires at least version `4.0.0`

Try `npm update -g webpack`

If that does not work

Try `npm install --save-dev webpack`

or with Yarn

Try `yarn add webpack --dev`