# Deploy React + Spring Boot JAR within service/process to AWS EC2 Linux Server

Tags: linux, reactjs, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, jar

I have a full stack React.js & Spring Boot Application and I'm trying to figure out a good way to have it deployed to AWS EC2 Linux Server where i can leave it running 24/7. My issue is I can run it as an executable jar on AWS EC2 and I can access it using my web browser from public IP address but when I close the terminal it stops the jar. What can I use to run it as a background service/process so it stays running in the background when I close the terminal? Tomcat seems to be only for war files.

I have it packaged as a jar file with embedded tomcat server and I used the frontend-maven-plugin from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817462/react-spring-boot-deployment) to package as a jar.

Server is Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-01460aa81365561fe

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>reactspringproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myproject</name>
    <description>React Spring Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        Tomcat dependency at runtime instead of compile time-->
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v12.14.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>6.9.0</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>Install our dependencies</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>Build our React App</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v12.14.0</nodeVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/react-client</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Copy my react client app into my Spring Boot target static folder</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/react-client/build</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I never got an answer so I just switched back to deploying as a WAR file. I embedded my React frontend code in the WAR and it's working on EC2.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the background process of Linux like this:

```
java -jar [YOUR JAR FILE NAME] &
```

The & sign at the end of this command tells the Linux to run the java as a process or a background job.