# Javascript and React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to build some UI in front of an existing Javascript code base. The UI needs to change/update dynamically as the user interacts with it.

I am familiar (no more experience than that) with writing javascript/jquery-based UIs. React appears to be very intuitive and I did a quick (and almost complete functionality that I need) prototype in the last two days - I guess seasoned React developers might only take a few hours to build what I came up with so far.

However, I don't like the fact that I need to run this React app on Node.js (on the server side).

- Did I get that right?
- I read about Babel standalone, but it is not recommended in production environments.
- Since I already have a backend (to be honest, even if I had to build it afresh, there's at least a 70% chance that I will choose Java)
- From the current app, all I need is a dynamically updating user interface that interacts with my Java backend.

**The question**
Is it possible to pre-compile the current React app I built into a bunch of pure JavaScript files?

Comment: the _build_ of your react app can be served as static files directly from your Java servlet or Spring MVC/Spring Boot static assets folder. You can read about the build [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build).

Comment: this will be helpful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817462/react-spring-boot-deployment

Comment: @RandyCasburn - that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> However, I don't like the fact that I need to run this React app on Node.js (on the server-side).

This is only true if you're deliberately using server-side rendering instead of the (more common) method of simply compiling the code to plain JavaScript and serving that compiled code. Once the code is compiled, that's it - you don't need to use Node anymore.

It'll be perfectly fine to have a Java backend *for the live server* while also using Node *only when you need compile the React code* (which can be completely separate from the live server). A common framework for beginners for compiling React to plain JS is [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app).